# C: Closing File Descriptors

Tags: c, unix, file-descriptor

how would I go about properly closing a file descriptor? I currently have to write a simple unix shell. For example, if the user entered `sort < someFile`, I have the following code:

```
freopen(commandArg[<location + 1],"r",stdin);
executeArg(commandArg);
fclose(stdout);
```

When I execute the command with execvp and everything, it works fine if I just exit my program. But if I want to keep looping and keep getting commands my programs fails, I get the error:

```
sort: write error: Bad file descriptor
sort: fflush failed: standard output: Bad file descriptor
```

I've read that its something to do with the `fclose(stdout)` because when it runs the `while` loop again, it tries to open after I've already closed it (I think). I've tried putting the `fclose(stdout)` at the end of my program but I still get errors.

Edit: I've tried taking out `fclose(stdout)`, but when I do that it my code seems to infinetly loop for some reason. A command like `ls` won't keep looping.

Comment: With regards to the edit, how do you know it infinitely loops?

Comment: Why are you opening an output file when the command has an **input** redirecetion?

Comment: Now you're reopening `stdin`, but you're closing `stdout`. I think you need to copy and paste the real code so we can see what you're **really** doing.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been freopen(commandArg[<location + 1],"r",stdin) and not stdout. I assume it infinitely loops because it keeps sorting my test file then at the very end it prints fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: `commandArg[<location + 1]` is obviously not real C either, while we're at it.

Comment: I'm assuming you are `fork()`ing a child before `exevp()` because `execvp()` doesn't return to caller. Whatever you do with the child's file descriptors, doesn't propagate back to parent. Each child will inherit the parent's file descriptor though. That will be the start state of your child process. I should use the term clone, instead of inherit.

Comment: Sorry, that was just to make it easier to follow. It basically just means commandArg at the location of the < + 1

Comment: Do you know what `freopen` *does*, by the way?

Comment: @immibis - maybe you should follow thru by asking the difference between file descriptor and file stream.

Comment: It might be better if you used `open()` and `dup2()`, rather than `freopen()`. As far as I can tell, there's no guarantee that `freopen()` will use the same FD when it opens the new file. And programs all expect their stdin to be FD 0.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it. Rather than call freopen before I call the execute command, I call it right before execvp in the actual function and it works